# Vaadin - How to bind a List of POJO

Tags: list, data-binding, combobox, vaadin, pojo

In Vaadin 7, I'm trying to bind my ComboBox of phone numbers to a list of POJO nested in a POJO.
For exemple: I have PersonVo that contains a List phones; and PersonCommunicationVo contains the value of the phone number.

What I used for binding the others properties of PersonVo is:

```
BeanFieldGroup<PersonVo>personBinder = new BeanFieldGroup<PersonVo>(PersonVo.class);
personBinder.setItemDataSource(person);
myFormLayout.addComponent(personBinder.buildAndBind("Firstname", "firstName"));
myFormLayout.addComponent(personBinder.buildAndBind("Country", "country.name"));
```

Here PersonVo:

```
@Table(name = "CONTACT.T_PERSON")
@Entity
@Audited
public class PersonVo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id",updatable = false)
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "personId")
    @AuditMappedBy(mappedBy = "personId")
    private List<PersonCommunicationVo> **phoneNumbers**;

    ...
```

and PersonCommunicationVo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT.PERSON_COMMUNICATION")
@Audited

public class PersonCommunicationVo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id",updatable = false)
    private Long persCommId;

    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COM_TYPE_ID")
    private CommunicationTypesVo communicationType;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String **value**;
```

And what I would like to do is to bind my combobox of phone number to the list **phoneNumbers** from PersonVo based on the **value** from PersonCommunicationVo. 
But the difficulty is to reach the right PersonCommunicationVo in the list base on what has been selected in the combobox. For exemple: I have selected the phone number +32 123 456 789  in the combobox and this value should be map to the phoneNumbers.get(indexOfSelectedItem).getValue().
In order to update the phone number, add a new one etc...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

maybe i didnt understand your datamodel, if so, could you please post PersonVo, PhoneVo(?) and PersonCommunicationVo and explain it a little further why you want to save it like you do. why does your personvo contain a List of phones? i've never worked with a beanfieldgroup before, but i think of something like:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox("Phones", person.getPhones())
personBinder.bind(cb, "phones");
myFormLayout.addComponent(cb);
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation and my bad English. I edited the question :)

Comment: ComboBox has just 1 item as a value, so it can't be bind to list property. I thought about table, but even with multiselect mode, you would need to select all elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this (java 1.7 syntax and Vaadin7):

```
...
    FieldGroup fGroup = new FieldGroup( new BeanItem<PersonVo> (personInstance) );
...
    BeanItemContainer<PersonCommunicationVo> numbers = new BeanItemContainer<>( PersonCommunicationVo.class );
    numbers.addAll( personInstance.getPhoneNumbers() );

    ComboBox phoneCombo = new ComboBox( "Phone Numbers", numbers );
    phoneCombo.setItemCaptionMode( ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY );
    phoneCombo.setItemCaptionPropertyId( "**value**" );

    fGroup.bind (phoneCombo, "**phoneNumbers**")

    myFormLayout.addComponent(phoneCombo);
...
```

Comment: ComboBox has just 1 item as a value, so it can't be bind to list property. I thought about table, but even with multiselect mode, you would need to select all elements.